# Root password check loop even after good password is set

Tags: bash, dialog, passwords, archlinux

I've made myself my script in order to install Archlinux in a semi-automatic mode.

But what I'm trying to do is check whether the root password is correctly set or not.

I've tried everything from awk, grep, /etc/shadow verification none of these seemed to work on my script.

I really need some help out there.

Here's my code : https://paste.sh/e_Iqqe57#rR16bpH_dY8xkgnebmk8tAjz

I'm willing to buy you a beer or whatever you want I'm so desperate right now haha

## EDIT :

paste.bin link : http://pastebin.com/r2MMtknm

Comment: just a tip, pastebin might be better to use, since this is all in plain non syntax text and looks like if someone wrote a shell script in a word document. And might be better to comment in english since most people here speak english so will help us debug the script better.

Comment: @jgr208 thanks dude for the tip. I just found how to solve my problem in the mean time

Comment: What about your code isn't working exactly? Are you not getting a value back from the command? Is the value not what you expect? Is it what you expect but the `[[`/`]]` test isn't working? Have you printed out the value you get back before you test it to see what it is?

Comment: Yes I did in a terminal which made me think there is something not working between arch-chroot and the awk command sent by chroot so maybe there is a bit of a bug or something else

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll let the question here since I found an anwser who may interest some of you guys :

In my condition to check whether root passwd is set or not, I changed the condition to this one :

```
cat /mnt/etc/shadow | awk -F: '/root/ { print $2 }'
```

So that, i no longer use arch-chroot which seems not working properly with an awk pipe.

If some of you are brave to check my code, could you confirm whether it is an issue or just me messing around with a not-so-useful long condition ?